# How to solve JVM Error while starting Graylog

Tags: elasticsearch, jvm, graylog

Hello i get an error while try to start graylog. SS belongs to server.log file. I just installed it and didn't change any default configuration.
Helps are appreciated.

[[image: server.log error1]

EDIT: I debugged the startup script and see my JAVA_HOME environment was not true, fixed this, then i run through logs and see there was password warning, it expects at least 16 characters long, changed the config file and runned it. It worked. Hope this helps to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because you're using JDK version 15+.
CMS collector has been deprecated in JDK 9 and related options were removed in JDK 15: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/51361

I don't know Graylog but you can either change its default startup script or use an older Java version.

Comment: Your answer was pretty simple and basic, but cause me to learn a lot of thing. 
Especially with this "you can either change its default startup script"

I started to debug the startup script, then see where it fails, fixed lots of thing and after 3 hour of deep work it works!

Thank you again,I appreciate!